# Broad match based on the values list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, matching

I have column `A` with values

```
  A
1 plum
2 orange
3 oranguice
4 cherry
5 cherry apple
6 apple
```

Column `B` contain to-remove-values

```
  B
1 apple
2 orang
```

At the moment i run in the column `C` the formula

`=WENN(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$2,A1)>0,"Delete","Keep")`

which inserts `Delete` and `Keep` into `C`, if something from `B` was found in `A`.

Now it works only for exact matches, like: it matches only `A6`.

**How could the formula be improved to work with broad matches**, like:

- if in `B1`stays `apple` - `A5` and `A6`should be matched,
- if in `B2` stays `orang` - `A2` and `A3` should be matched,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

- German version: `=WENN(SUMMENPRODUKT(ZÄHLENWENN(A1;"*"&$B$1:$B$2&"*"))>0;"Delete";"Keep")`
- English version: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$2&"*"))>0,"Delete","Keep")`

Results:

[image]

Comment: no luck, the same output :( It was correctly written in german notation so `=WENN(SUMMENPRODUKT(ZÄHLENWENN(A1;"*"&$B$1:$B$2&"*"))>0;"Delete";"Keep")` . Could the fail be caused by german Excel? My translation seems to be correct...

Comment: @Evgeniy That's strange, works for me just fine, see attached image of results I get.

Answer (score 3):

Mine is in English, You will need to translate:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$1:$B$2,A1))),"Delete","Keep")
```

[image]